# How to create tables as InnoDB in jpa?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa

Im trying to create tables as innodb in order to use foreign keys but i got failed my tables  are staying as myIssam engine!

My mysql version is 5.7.26
and here is my application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/general_security?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=basil
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.type=debug
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
hibernate.dialect.storage_engine=innodb
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=50

server.servlet.context-path=/generalSecurity
spring.jmx.default-domain: general_security
```

i also tried

```
spring.jpa.database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect.storage_engine=innodb
```

Comment: that works perfect, thanks.
but why my configs were not worked ?

Comment: at a first look you use the a config for mysql 5  ...  not for mysql 5.7 .. so with wrong (or not campatible) param are not used  and are used  the default value  (myisam)

Comment: That would be great
Thanks for helping and explaining